# .htaccess hotlink protection doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

can you correct & inform me  please. My issue is my .htaccess hotlink protection doesn't work. I am on a shared server with .htaccess suppport. (SEO friendly linking works)
My domain type is `http://www.mydomain.p.ht` OR `http://mydomain.p.ht`

my 2 sources for my trials are:

1. http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/
2. stackoverflow

I did not forget to replace `mydomain` with my real domain

### my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# hotlink protection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.p.ht [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css)$ - [NC,F,L]

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# File caching is another famous approach in optimizing website loading time
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

#SEO friendly linking
...
...
```

### I also tried

## 1

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.p.ht [NC]
RewriteRule \.(flv)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

## 2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain\.p\.ht/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean? Is it still possible to hotlink your images from other sites or can't you see the images on your own site?

Comment: I see my images. But can not provide hotlink protection for my images from other sites. tested on also : htaccesstools.com/test-hotlink-protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods are correct and working fine. Since your have caching enabled for these files most likely `http://htaccesstools.com/test-hotlink-protection` is showing you cached snapshot of the image. If you really want to test it create a html file on your localhost or some other host other than `mydomain.p.ht` host and include this line (replace /images/home.gif` with the path of an actual gif file):

```
<img border="0" src="http://mydomain.p.ht/images/home.gif">
```

And see if image shows up in browser or not. If you have Firbug network tab opened while doing this you should see Forbidden 403 status for above image.